# Unable to stream asf to RTMP using gstreamer

Tags: video, gstreamer, rtmp, asf

I am playing around with `gstreamer` to stream various sources to `RTMP`.
It works fine with `RTSP` and `MP4` sources but when i try `asf` source it dosen't work.

Pipeline i am using is: `gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="C:\\Users\\user1\\Download
s\\Video\\test2.asf" ! asfparse ! asfdemux ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test'`

output i get is :

`Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstAsfParse:asfparse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-ms-asf, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstASFDemux:asfdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-ms-asf, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvMux:flvmux0: streamable = true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvMux:flvmux0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-flv, streamheader=(buffer)< 464c..., 1200.... >
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstRTMPSink:rtmpsink0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-flv, streamheader=(buffer)< 464c.., 1200... >
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Got EOS from element "pipeline0".      <<<-------- why?
Execution ended after 0:00:00.001711787
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...`

The file plays fine using `playbin`.

**stream information:**

[image: stream info]

If i change the pipeline to re-encode the video then there is no error in streaming side, but neither `VLC` not `gstreamer playbin` is able to play it, they just seem to try forever.

Pipeline used for re-encoding and streaming:

`gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location="C:\\Users\\user1\\Downloads\\Video\
\test2.asf" ! asfparse ! asfdemux ! decodebin ! x264enc ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://127.0.0.1:1935/live/test2'`

Comment: I don't think the ASF codec has a specification to be transported over RTMP.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch yes that is why i am demuxing it and remuxing it in flv.

Comment: That is still not supported. That codec has to way to be muxed inside the RTMP protocol. You would need to transcode into H.264.

Comment: @FlorianZwoch please see my edit

Comment: I suggest to check for GST_DEBUG=3 errors..